# Передача функции ссылку переменной. static_cast<>. C++

Tags: c++, функции, память

1) Насколько я знаю, static_cast<> создает копию переменной но уже в другом формате. Вот код

```
// 1
int x (7);
float y = 200/static_cast<float>(x)
// 2
float *xClone = new float(7);
floay y = 200/xClone;
delete xClone;
```

Чем `static_cast` эффективнее и насколЬко?

2) допустим, мне надо поработать с какой то переменной в функции типа `void`. Я отправляю туда ссылку на эту переменную. Создается копия этой переменной или функция напрямую работает с моей переменной которую я отправил в функцию?

Comment: У вас мягкий знак одновременно с шифтом срабатывает что ли?

Answer (score 2):

1. Эффективнее **очень** намного. Потому что выделение памяти для одного действия - это их пушки по воробьям!

А вообще - не морочьте голову ни себе, ни людям :) и пишите

```
float y = 200.0/x;
```

Кстати, все равно ваше

```
floay y = 200/xClone;
```

не скомпилируется - из-за неверного типа и того, что на указатель делить нельзя :)

2. Работает напрямую с переменной.
3. Не задавайте совершенно разные вопросы в одном...

Comment: И того, что `floay` это не `float` )

Comment: @Harry, с добрым утром!  Что значит :   это их пушки по воробьям?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Выделение памяти обращается к диспетчеру памяти, тот выполняет поиск свободного места, выделение памяти с заполнением кучи служебных полей, копирование, потом освобождение. Результат - замедление на порядок... Вот простейший пример: https://ideone.com/yapuDn

Comment: @Harry, дело в том, что я не понел смысль выражения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А, ну это фразеологизм в русском языке, означающий применение совершенно не подходящего средства (как правило, слишком мощного или затратного) для решения мелкой задачи. Например, разогреть котельную, чтобы выпить чашку чая, построить электростанцию, чтоб зарядить аккумулятор, выделять память для переменной для одного деления :)

Comment: Ладно, а почему их пушка, чья?  Если бы было написано без слова "их", я бы понел...

Comment: Блин, ну не заметил я! з и х рядом, палец ткнул не в ту клавишу! А проверялка орфографии, понятно, не отреагировала. Извините, но теперь уже изменить не могу - время вышло :(

Answer (score 0):

```
int x (7);
float y = 200/static_cast<float>(x)
```

Равнозначен такому коду:

```
int x (7);
float __tempor = x ;  
float y = 200/__tempor;
```

Переменная `__tempor` как и все локальные переменные могут хранится в стеке или в регистрах процессора, как оптимизация всё провернула. При выделении памяти в куче происходит торможение всех остальных нитей для организации выделения памяти. Далее в программе когда потребуется значение переменной, будет постоянно требоваться доступ этой ячейке памяти (оптимизация не поможет, так-как другие нити могли изменить значение). А если переменная локальная, то всё будет под контролем компилятора (и место хранения и оптимизация).